# Difference between Dojo Data and dojo ajax

Tags: ajax, dojo

I am wondering when to use dojo data and for example 'dojo.data.itemfilereadstore' to get data from the server and when you should choose to use ajax and for example 'dojo.xhrGet' to retrieve data from the server.

Let me take as an example my homepage where I give my user an overview off items. He can filter this in a way that he can choos to retrieve items off type A, type B or items off type A and B.

Should I use:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url: "get-items.php", //json result

    load: function(response) {
        showItems(respone.items);
    }
});
```

OR 
    dojo.data.itemfilereadstore

Answer (score 0):

Those two things have vastly different purposes:

dojo.xhr is a **data transport** - its main purpose is sendig and receiving messages from the server.

dojo.data is a **data store** - its main purpose is to represent a collection of data items, supporting things like querying, monitoring for updates, etc. The fact that some data stores support being initialized directly from the server is just a coincidence. *Those features are there purely for convenience.*

So

- Use dojo.xhrGet if you just need to fetch data once and then are done with it.
- Use a data store if you want to use the extra functionality from the datastore interface. (like serving as a model for Tree widgets or watching for updates in an MVC style)

---

Btw, since 1.6 there is a new [dojo.store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store.html) API as a leaner alternative to dojo.data. Keep that in mind when deciding wether to use a datastore.

Comment: Ok thank you verry much for the answer! I will keep it in mind and I finnaly get the difference.